# Relationship between a normal subgroup and a stabilizer

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group and $$N\unlhd G$$ Suppose that $G$ acts transitively on a set $\Omega$ and that
$N$ fixes some $x \in\Omega$, namely $n\cdot x = x$ for all $n \in N$.

How are  $N$ and the stabilizer $Gx$ related?

My thoughts: 
- I have seen somewhere that 'if the group action is transitive, then the stabilizer is normal' and that a 'normal subgroup normalizes a stabilizer' but I'm not sure if these statements are true. If they are could I, first of all, show that the stabilizer is a subgroup then go on to show it is a normal subgroup? Another thought I had was about cardinality so since $G$ is transitive if $N$ is normal then all orbits of $N$ on $X$ have the same cardinality...

I may be completely wrong so any tips or hints would be very appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The two statements you quote are false. For example $G=S_n$ acts transitively but the stabiliser of a point $G_x$ is not normal in $G$, also $A_n$ is normal in $S_n$, but does not normalise $G_x$.

A subgroup $H$ of $G$ fixes $x$ if and only if $H\le G_x$.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure they were correct, but didn't know what else to do to solve it. So if H is a normal subgroup of G, then it still fixes x?

Comment: Isn't it assumed that $H$ fixes $x$?

Comment: oh sorry yes, forgive me. What I meant to say was, if H is a normal subgroup is H still a subgroup of Gx or is it a normal subgroup of Gx?

Comment: correct, $H$ would be a normal subgroup of $G_x$

Comment: thank you. so just to clarify, as I'm not sure I fully understand. How would you go about proving this?

Comment: I think the fact you are looking for, is that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$, then $N$ is a normal subgroup. (This is an easy exercise, try it.) This applies to your case with $G_x$ playing the role of $H$.